# Changing ImageUrl using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have following hyperlink in asp.net:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="a" runat="server" ImageUrl="1.png" NavigateUrl="https://google.com/"></asp:HyperLink>
```

I want to change ImageUrl through jquery to 2.png. I am trying this but it is not working:

```
$("#a").attr("ImageUrl", "2.png");
```

Comment: Check the html that <asp:HyperLink> creates. Html uses the src attribute and not "ImageUrl".

Comment: @SérgioMichels - i tried using this also: $("#a").attr("src", "2.png"); and that does not work either.

Comment: did you checked the html that asp generated?

Comment: Is the image 2.png in the same folder as the web page? Otherwise you need to specify a folder location in the "src" property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things here...

I have found that you can't select an element this way if you include the runat attribute.  You will need to reference the object like this...

```
var hyperLink = document.getElementById("<%= a.ClientID %>");
```

That should get you the correct object.  Now, the asp:HyperLink saves as an anchor with an image attached.  So you can reference and change the source like this.

```
$(hyperLink).find("img").attr('src', '2.png');
```

Answer (score 3):

imageurl doesn't exist when it renders client side. It should transform your asp control to something like this.

```
<a href="/myurl.aspx"><img src="/my/image.jpg" /></a>
```

you should use something like

```
$("#<%=a.ClientID%>").find("img").attr("src", "2.png");
```

I didn't test this, but it should get you on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the markup as rendered by .NET rather than the server side code.

So, by looking at the markup, you'll see that this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="a" runat="server" ImageUrl="1.png" NavigateUrl="https://google.com/"></asp:HyperLink>
```

renders this (At least in .net 4.0):

```
<a id="a" href="https://google.com/">
    <img alt="" src="1.png">
</a>
```

While in my little test project the markup id matches the webforms id, this isn't always the case.

So, to change the image with jquery, you'd just say:

```
$('img', $('#<%= a.ClientID %>')).attr('src', '2.png');
```

This finds the image tag inside the tag with the ID of a and changes it's src attribute.

A word of advice - use better ID names than 'a'. You're markup needs to be easily decipherable. Also, when dealing with webforms (like I said above), always use <%= tagid.ClientID %> in the jquery.